# Long running query CORS issue in GCP

Tags: node.js, cors, google-compute-engine, nestjs

I have a frontend app (Angular) and backend in Google Compute engine done with NodeJS (NestJS framework)
The frontend is calling REST APIs which then calls a 3rd party API

I have 1 API call which is a fairly long running query, it fetches a lot of data from the 3rd party API and then stores the data to mysql (in google cloud also)

All of the API calls work fine with the 3rd party API but with the API call that takes 2-3 min to respond I get:

`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I have in NodeJS setup the cors with the cors module so that should be fine since all the other calls are fine

The timeout on the endpoint on the server side is set to 7 minutes and the calls takes about 2-3min to respond (in localhost). I can see the process continues in the backend to process and it finished fine but for some reason browser throws the above error

Any ideas what's going on here ? All of this works fine in localhost

-Jani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue, I am using nginx as a proxy in google compute engine and I needed to increase the timeout values

```
proxy_connect_timeout       600;
proxy_send_timeout          600;
proxy_read_timeout          600;
send_timeout                600;
```